# How to attach data to socket connection in order to get this data on `SessionDisconnectEvent`?

Tags: java, angular, spring-boot, websocket, stomp

**What I want to achieve**

I want to get my string variable I am using as `@DestinationVariable`, called `lobbyName`, when socket disconnects using `@EventListener` on server side:

```
@Component
public class WebSocketEventListener {

    private SimpMessageSendingOperations messagingTemplate;

    public WebSocketEventListener(SimpMessageSendingOperations messagingTemplate) {
        this.messagingTemplate = messagingTemplate;
    }

    @EventListener
    public void handleWebSocketDisconnectListener(SessionDisconnectEvent event) {
        //here I want to get my data
    }
}
```

**My problem**

I have been trying to get `lobbyName` using `SessionDisonnectEvent` but I don't know how, when and where to put this `lobbyName` in order to have it in `SessionDisconnectEvent`.

**What I have been trying**

On Server Side:

```
@Controller
public class WebSocketController {

    private final SimpMessagingTemplate template;

    WebSocketController(SimpMessagingTemplate template) {
        this.template = template;
    }

    public void pokeLobby(@DestinationVariable String lobbyName, SocketMessage message) {
//        This didn't work 
//        Map<String, Object> headers = new HashMap<>();
//        headers.put("lobbyName", lobbyName);
//        this.template.convertAndSend("/lobby/"+lobbyName.toLowerCase(), message, headers);
        this.template.convertAndSend("/lobby/"+lobbyName.toLowerCase(), message);
    }
}
```

Is it possible to do on client side? :

```
  connectToLobbyWebSocket(lobbyName: string): void {
    const ws = new SockJS(this.addressStorage.apiAddress + '/socket');
    this.stompClient = Stomp.over(ws);
    // this.stompClient.debug = null;
    const that = this;
    this.stompClient.connect({}, function () {
      that.stompClient.subscribe('/lobby/' + lobbyName, (message) => {
        if (message.body) {
          that.socketMessage.next(message.body); //client logic
        }
      });
    });
  }
```

**EDIT (progress)**

Since I can easily get `sessionId` on `SessionDisconnectEvent` I have decided to change `sessionId` (upon handshake) to something like `playerId:lobbyName:uuid`
I don't feel very comfortable with this solution so if you have any suggestions I am all ears.

```
const ws = new SockJS(this.addressStorage.apiAddress + '/socket', null, {
  sessionId: function (): string {
    return that.authManager.playerId + ':' + lobbyName + ':' + uuid();
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can send *lobbyName* in the body of the message as attribute and get it in the listner like this :

```
@EventListener
public void handleWebSocketDisconnectListener(SessionDisconnectEvent event) {
    StompHeaderAccessor headerAccessor = StompHeaderAccessor.wrap(event.getMessage());
    String lobbyName = (String) headerAccessor.getSessionAttributes().get("lobbyName");
    if(lobbyName != null) {
        SocketMessage message = new SocketMessage();
        messagingTemplate.convertAndSend("/topic/public/"+lobbyName, message);
    }
}
```